# When using AcceptEx and lpfnAcceptEx equally, only lpfnAcceptEx throws an error

Tags: winsock

In the AcceptEx part of the code, the address information is written to the buffer normally, but when I check the lpfnAcceptEx part by calling GetAcceptExSockaddrs later, the local and remote addresses are nullptr. Do you have any idea why?
If it's AcceptEx, everything is fine

```
Server server(8000);
    LPSession ses = nullptr;

    GUID GuidDisconnectEx = WSAID_DISCONNECTEX;
    GUID GuidAcceptEx = WSAID_ACCEPTEX;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        DWORD dwBytes;
        SOCKADDR_IN caddr;
        int addrlen = sizeof(caddr);
        ZeroMemory(&caddr, addrlen);

        ses = server.Add_Session(new Session(&server));

        WSAIoctl(ses->sock, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
            &GuidAcceptEx,sizeof(GuidAcceptEx),
            &ses->lpfnAcceptEx, sizeof(ses->lpfnAcceptEx),
            &dwBytes, NULL, NULL);

        WSAIoctl(ses->sock, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
            &GuidDisconnectEx, sizeof(GuidDisconnectEx),
            &ses->lpfnDisconnectEx, sizeof(ses->lpfnDisconnectEx),
            &dwBytes, NULL, NULL);

        ses->lpfnAcceptEx(server.listen_sock, ses->sock, &ses->aio->buf, 0,
            sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, NULL,
            reinterpret_cast<LPOVERLAPPED>(&ses->aio->over));

        AcceptEx(server.listen_sock, ses->sock, &ses->aio->buf, 0,
            sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, NULL,
            reinterpret_cast<LPOVERLAPPED>(&ses->aio->over));



        if (i == 49)
            cout << "Ready" << endl;
    }
```

```
PSOCKADDR pRemoteSocketAddr = nullptr;
    PSOCKADDR pLocalSocketAddr = nullptr;
    INT pRemoteSocketAddrLength = 0;
    INT pLocalSocketAddrLength = 0;


    GetAcceptExSockaddrs(
        &session->aio->buf, 0,
        sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16,
        &pLocalSocketAddr, &pLocalSocketAddrLength, &pRemoteSocketAddr, &pRemoteSocketAddrLength);

    SOCKADDR_IN remoteAddr = *(reinterpret_cast<PSOCKADDR_IN>(pRemoteSocketAddr));
```

Comment: Asynchronous operations work fine for both the former and the latter. The only thing lpfnAcceptEx can't do is write an address to a buffer.

Comment: Resolved. It seems that functions obtained by function pointer should be used with functions obtained by function pointer in the same way. I'm learning, so I was ignorant.